# Why is my code printing ".!canvas.!entry"?

Tags: python, button, canvas, tkinter

I don't understand what is going on. I have defined 2 functions. 1 function displays text, entry boxes, and a submit button. I have it so that when the submit button is pressed, it prints the information the user put inside of the entry boxes. I've shortened my code for easier readability.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


canvas_width = 360
canvas_height = 525
file = r"C:\Users\kraak\Desktop\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.2\borderedpaper.GIF"
master = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(master, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)

old_img = PhotoImage(file=file)
new_img = old_img.subsample(3, 3)
canvas.create_image(-11, -10, anchor=NW, image=new_img)
canvas.create_window(0, 0, height=1, width=1, anchor=NW)
canvas.create_text(0, 0, text="Test")
e1 = Entry(canvas)

def callback():
    print(e1)

def answer():
    e1 = Entry(canvas)
    canvas.create_window(250, 100, window=e1, height=15, width=100)
    label = Label(text="Enter a word.")
    label.place(x=40, y=90)

    e2 = Entry(canvas)
    canvas.create_window(250, 125, window=e2, height=15, width=100)
    label = Label(text="Enter a word.")
    label.place(x=40, y=115)

    button = Button(text="Submit.", command=callback)
    button.place(x=150, y=460)

answer()
canvas.pack()


mainloop()
```

Comment: Because you're printing `e1`, which is an entry. What did you expect the behavior would be?

Comment: Perhaps you want `e1.get()`.

Comment: I am trying to take the entries from the user and print them. Eventually I want the entry boxes to go away and have the answers displayed in the canvas. I'm just testing functionality right now. I think I figured it out. I moved everything except the last 2 lines outside of the answer function.

Comment: Your title implies it's printing exclamation points. Is it really? That seems highly unlikely, and the code you posted doesn't show exclamation marks either.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have run the code in linux and it does print ".!canvas.!entry". I guess that the way widgets are named is plateform specific.